# Making POD classes movable

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I have a POD class and I want to make it movable for efficiency. I keep all the data in a `std::array` member object, and I make my public member variables references to parts of this `std::array` object. By doing this, now I am able to move the entire data by moving the `std::array` instance in the move constructor (I know that it is not literally a POD class anymore after writing constructors.).

Is this a good method of doing this? Does it actually move the data? See the code output below: After moving the `std::array`, I observe that both objects have the same values. It looks like it doesn't move, but it copies the data. What is the problem here?

```
#include <array>

class MyPodClass
{
    private:
        typedef double  TYPE_x;
        typedef double  TYPE_y;
        typedef double  TYPE_z;
        typedef int     TYPE_p;
        typedef int     TYPE_r;
        typedef int     TYPE_s;
        typedef char    TYPE_k;
        typedef char    TYPE_l;
        typedef char    TYPE_m;
        typedef float   TYPE_a;
        typedef float   TYPE_b;
        typedef float   TYPE_c;

        enum TypeSizes
        {
            STARTING_POSITION_x = 0,
            STARTING_POSITION_y = STARTING_POSITION_x + sizeof(TYPE_x),
            STARTING_POSITION_z = STARTING_POSITION_y + sizeof(TYPE_y),
            STARTING_POSITION_p = STARTING_POSITION_z + sizeof(TYPE_z),
            STARTING_POSITION_r = STARTING_POSITION_p + sizeof(TYPE_p),
            STARTING_POSITION_s = STARTING_POSITION_r + sizeof(TYPE_r),
            STARTING_POSITION_k = STARTING_POSITION_s + sizeof(TYPE_s),
            STARTING_POSITION_l = STARTING_POSITION_k + sizeof(TYPE_k),
            STARTING_POSITION_m = STARTING_POSITION_l + sizeof(TYPE_l),
            STARTING_POSITION_a = STARTING_POSITION_m + sizeof(TYPE_m),
            STARTING_POSITION_b = STARTING_POSITION_a + sizeof(TYPE_a),
            STARTING_POSITION_c = STARTING_POSITION_b + sizeof(TYPE_b),
            END_POSITION        = STARTING_POSITION_c + sizeof(TYPE_c),
        };

        std::array<unsigned char, END_POSITION> MovableBulkData;

    public:
        MyPodClass()
            :   //x(*static_cast<TYPE_x*>(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_x])),  // ERROR: Invalid type conversion. Why?
                x(*(TYPE_x*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_x])),
                y(*(TYPE_y*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_y])),
                z(*(TYPE_z*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_z])),
                p(*(TYPE_p*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_p])),
                r(*(TYPE_r*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_r])),
                s(*(TYPE_s*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_s])),
                k(*(TYPE_k*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_k])),
                l(*(TYPE_l*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_l])),
                m(*(TYPE_m*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_m])),
                a(*(TYPE_a*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_a])),
                b(*(TYPE_b*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_b])),
                c(*(TYPE_c*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_c]))
        {
        }

        MyPodClass(MyPodClass && RValue)
            :   MovableBulkData(std::move(RValue.MovableBulkData)),
                x(*(TYPE_x*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_x])),
                y(*(TYPE_y*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_y])),
                z(*(TYPE_z*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_z])),
                p(*(TYPE_p*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_p])),
                r(*(TYPE_r*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_r])),
                s(*(TYPE_s*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_s])),
                k(*(TYPE_k*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_k])),
                l(*(TYPE_l*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_l])),
                m(*(TYPE_m*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_m])),
                a(*(TYPE_a*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_a])),
                b(*(TYPE_b*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_b])),
                c(*(TYPE_c*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_c]))
        {
        }

        const MyPodClass & operator=(MyPodClass && RValue)
        {
            MovableBulkData = std::move(RValue.MovableBulkData);
            return *this;
        }

        TYPE_x & x;
        TYPE_y & y;
        TYPE_z & z;
        TYPE_p & p;
        TYPE_r & r;
        TYPE_s & s;
        TYPE_k & k;
        TYPE_l & l;
        TYPE_m & m;
        TYPE_a & a;
        TYPE_b & b;
        TYPE_c & c;
};

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[], wchar_t *envp[])
{
    MyPodClass PodObject1, PodObject2;
    PodObject1.y = 3.4;
    PodObject1.s = 4;
    PodObject1.m = 'm';
    PodObject1.a = 2.3f;

    std::cout << "PodObject1.y = " << PodObject1.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject1.s = " << PodObject1.s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject1.m = " << PodObject1.m << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject1.a = " << PodObject1.a << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "PodObject2.y = " << PodObject2.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject2.s = " << PodObject2.s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject2.m = " << PodObject2.m << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject2.a = " << PodObject2.a << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Moving PodObject1 to PodObject2..." << std::endl << std::endl;
    PodObject2 = std::move(PodObject1);

    std::cout << "PodObject1.y = " << PodObject1.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject1.s = " << PodObject1.s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject1.m = " << PodObject1.m << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject1.a = " << PodObject1.a << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "PodObject2.y = " << PodObject2.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject2.s = " << PodObject2.s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject2.m = " << PodObject2.m << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject2.a = " << PodObject2.a << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Modifying PodObject1 and PodObject2..." << std::endl << std::endl;
    PodObject1.s = 5;
    PodObject2.m = 'n';

    std::cout << "PodObject1.y = " << PodObject1.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject1.s = " << PodObject1.s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject1.m = " << PodObject1.m << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject1.a = " << PodObject1.a << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "PodObject2.y = " << PodObject2.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject2.s = " << PodObject2.s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject2.m = " << PodObject2.m << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PodObject2.a = " << PodObject2.a << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    _wsystem(L"timeout /t 60 /nobreak");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
PodObject1.y = 3.4
PodObject1.s = 4
PodObject1.m = m
PodObject1.a = 2.3

PodObject2.y = -9.25596e+61
PodObject2.s = -858993460
PodObject2.m = ╠
PodObject2.a = -1.07374e+08

Moving PodObject1 to PodObject2...

PodObject1.y = 3.4
PodObject1.s = 4
PodObject1.m = m
PodObject1.a = 2.3

PodObject2.y = 3.4
PodObject2.s = 4
PodObject2.m = m
PodObject2.a = 2.3

Modifying PodObject1 and PodObject2...

PodObject1.y = 3.4
PodObject1.s = 5
PodObject1.m = m
PodObject1.a = 2.3

PodObject2.y = 3.4
PodObject2.s = 4
PodObject2.m = n
PodObject2.a = 2.3
```

Comment: All of these values are stored directly in the object itself. Moving is useful when an object containers a pointer to some allocated memory elsewhere, which can be stolen. That isn't the case here. That's basically the difference between `std::array` and `std::vector`.

Comment: I doubt: `x(*(TYPE_x*)(&MovableBulkData[STARTING_POSITION_x]))` will be quicker or any way better than just copying the value.

Comment: You may have alignment issue with your buffer...

Comment: PODs are already movable.

Comment: stop this nonsense at once. a POD class is the most efficient data structure you'll ever write.

Answer (score 7):

This is a misuse of move semantics.  Since your class contains a number of simple data members like `int` and `float`, there is really nothing to move.  You'd be better off with `memcpy()`, which is probably close to what your compiler gives you for free if you just write the class the normal, naive way, with no `std::array` and no pointer gymnastics.

Move semantics would have been useful here if your class contained e.g. a std::string, because std::string uses dynamically allocated memory which can be "moved" (read: adopted) into the target of a move.

The above of course means that you could "fix" your problem by dynamically allocating the array, which would allow you to move it.  But in the end this would be a baroque way to achieve the effect of using a trivial POD class with no gymnastics and storing it in a `std::unique_ptr`, which of course enables move semantics.